# Why does JavaScript files reloading not work with sbt-aspectj in Play project?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.1, sbt-aspectj

I'm using [sbt-aspectj](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj) plugin with [Play Framework](http://playframework.org/) 2.1.5.

When I hit refresh, all resources including javascript files are not reloaded automatically -- I need to restart the server in order to get the expected result.

It seems that I'm missing something in the build, but can't really find what it could be and hence the question.

Here's `plugins.sbt` file:

```
//  Used to weave Logger around controller methods
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-aspectj" % "0.9.4")
```

`Build.scala` file:

```scala
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj.AspectjKeys.inputs
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj.{Aspectj, aspectjSettings, compiledClasses}
import play.Project._
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object Build extends Build {

  val appName    = "frontend"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val frontEndAppDependencies = Seq(
    javaCore,
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.6.6",

    "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.1-RC2",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-quartz-scheduler" % "1.2.0-akka-2.1.x",    
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.2.0",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.2.0",
    "org.apache.directory.studio" % "org.apache.commons.io" % "2.4",
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9"

  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, frontEndAppDependencies).settings(
      resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal,
      lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(_ / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" ** "main.less"),
      coffeescriptOptions := Seq("bare")
    )
    // todo : activate aspectj before release to enable  log filters ; this configuration is deactivated because of the resources auto reloading bug
    .settings(aspectjSettings: _*).settings(inputs in Aspectj <+= compiledClasses,
      products in Compile <<= products in Aspectj,
      products in Runtime <<= products in Compile

    )  
}
```

Comment: Could you github a basic Play project to reproduce the issue? It's going to be so much easier with a project ready for `git clone`. I also think it should be reported to sbt-aspectj.